# Android JSON Rails parsing problem

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json

In my Android application I've try to send Cyrillic text in JSON to Rails but got error

```
StandardError (Invalid JSON string: '{"from_address":". , 4","from_location":{"lat":55.13718833333334,"lng":61.40910333333333},"authentication_token":"487884511081085287658949531157857112691099771"}'):
```

Has anyone faced that?

Comment: Can you edit to include the full json string from rails and the android json parsing code. Also are you using .to_json or rolling the json yourself as rails json encoding is usually perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to correctly set the `Content-Type` header in the POST request to include the proper charset. Something like this:

```
Content-Type: application/json ; charset=UTF-8
```

Obviously this works if you are using UTF-8: change the charset to whatever you are actually using in the Android client.

Comment: I've done that: httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");